# Checking which pypi packages are Py3k-only

Tags: python

I looked at the [pypi classifiers](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=list_classifiers) and [some guide](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPiXmlRpc) to help me write the following script, and here's me wondering if it can be improved:

```
import xmlrpc.client

# pypi language version classifiers
PY3 =  ["Programming Language :: Python :: 3"]
PY2 =  ["Programming Language :: Python :: 2"]
PY27 = ["Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7"]
PY26 = ["Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6"]
PY25 = ["Programming Language :: Python :: 2.5"]
PY24 = ["Programming Language :: Python :: 2.4"]
PY23 = ["Programming Language :: Python :: 2.3"]

def main():
    client = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('http://pypi.python.org/pypi')

    # get module metadata
    py3names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY3)]
    py2names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY2)]
    py27names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY27)]
    py26names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY26)]
    py25names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY25)]
    py24names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY24)]
    py23names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY23)]

    cnt = 0
    for py3name in py3names:
        if py3name not in py27names \
           and py3name not in py26names \
           and py3name not in py25names \
           and py3name not in py24names \
           and py3name not in py23names \
           and py3name not in py2names:
            cnt += 1

    print("Python3-only packages: {}".format(cnt))

main()
```

**Sidenote**:

```
$ time python3 py3k-only.py 
Python3-only packages: 259

real    0m17.312s
user    0m0.324s
sys 0m0.012s
```

In addition, can you spot any functionality bugs in there?  Will it give accurate results, assuming that pypi has correct info?

Comment: [**a more complete script**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9012768)

Comment: @jamal you killed the evolution of the Question, and now the Answer looks odd

Comment: The answer was never edited, though.  It had to correspond to just the original code.

Comment: Yeah, but look at *Why do you have a single string in a list?* for example. You got rid of that part of the original Question.

Comment: I still see that in this code.

Comment: Oh, I see my mistake. I still unlove your Edit, because my Question showed the progress as I made the code better, as a result of feedback. You simply made that disappear. Your deed makes me sad.

Comment: Only thing I like is title change.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's to help make the post easier to follow.  You can still post a follow-up if you'd like further review, or a self-answer if you want to show your improvements (but they'll have to explain the changes).  The Help Center now explains this in depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import xmlrpc.client

# pypi language version classifiers
PY3 =  ["Programming Language :: Python :: 3"]
```

Why do you have a single string in a list?

```
PY2 =  ["Programming Language :: Python :: 2"]
PY27 = ["Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7"]
PY26 = ["Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6"]
PY25 = ["Programming Language :: Python :: 2.5"]
PY24 = ["Programming Language :: Python :: 2.4"]
PY23 = ["Programming Language :: Python :: 2.3"]
```

You should put all these strings in one list.

```
def main():
    client = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('http://pypi.python.org/pypi')

    # get module metadata
    py3names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY3)]
    py2names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY2)]
    py27names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY27)]
    py26names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY26)]
    py25names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY25)]
    py24names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY24)]
    py23names = [name[0] for name in client.browse(PY23)]
```

If you put the python 2.x versions in a one list, you should be able to fetch all this data
into one big list rather then all of these lists.

```
    cnt = 0
```

Don't uselessly abbreviate, spell out `counter`

```
    for py3name in py3names:
        if py3name not in py27names \
           and py3name not in py26names \
           and py3name not in py25names \
           and py3name not in py24names \
           and py3name not in py23names \
           and py3name not in py2names:
            cnt += 1
```

I'd do something like: `python3_only = [name for name in py3name if py3name not in py2names]`. Then I'd get the number of packages as a len of that.

```
    print("Python3-only packages: {}".format(cnt))

main()
```

Usually practice is to the call to main inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` so that it only gets run if this script is the main script.

Comment: I think you meant `py3only = [name for name in py3names if name not in py2names]`?

Comment: BTW, with your suggested change to put all Python 2 classifiers in one list, the only modules that get excluded are those which match all the Python 2 classifiers. That is, my output includes a lot of packages that also have Python 2 versions.

Comment: @Tshepang, yes on the first comment, not if you do it properly on the second comment. I didn't expressly state how to do it, but you can go through the list, pass each element to the client.browse() one at a time, and then combine the lists.

Comment: @Tshepang, yes that's the idea. But you'd be better off to use a list literal instead of the append lines to build `PY2` you might also consider using a nested list comprehension in the fetch.

Comment: @Tshepang, `    py2names = [name[0] for classifier in PY2 
                        for name in client.browse([classifier])]`